# qsort function in C unexpected behaviour?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

I am experiencing weird and unexpected behaviour of the **qsort()** function. I have my list of nodes, and every of them contains two values based on which I want to sort my list (technically, an array).

**For example:**

If I have an original array that looks like this (1st element is *p*, 2nd element is *t*):

[0,10|1], [0.05|0], [0,10|0], [0,05|2], [0,10|2], [0,15|1], [0,05|1]

After it is sorted, it should look like this:

[0,05|0], [0,05|1], [0,05|2], [0,10|0], [0,10|1], [0,10|2], [0,15|1].

*Struct node:*

```
typedef struct node{
    int t;
    double p;
}node;
```

*Compare function*, called like `qsort(nodes, num_of_node, sizeof(node), compare_pairs);`

```
static int compare_pairs(const void *n1, const void *n2){

const node *na1= n1;
const node *na2= n2;

if(na1->p < na2->p) return -1;
if(na1->p > na2->p) return 1;

// At this point, value p is equal, so I am sorting based on t

if(na1->t < na2->t) return -1;
if(na1->t > na2->t) return 1;

return 0;
```

**Problem**

**The unwanted behaviour starts at *3. STEP* which looks like this:**

**List: [0.10 | 2]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]**

**And should look like this:**

**List: [0.10 | 2]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.25 | 999]**

Initial list:
[0.25 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.05| 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Creating (new) node 0.100000...

List: [0.05 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.05 | 999]  [0.10 | 1]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Creating (new) node 0.100000...

List: [0.05 | 999]  [0.10 | 1]  [0.10 | 2]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.050000...

Erasing (min) node 0.100000...

Creating (new) node 0.150000...

List: [0.10 | 2]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.100000...

Erasing (min) node 0.100000...

Erasing (new) node 0.200000...

List: [0.10 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.20 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.100000...

Erasing (min) node 0.150000...

Creating (new) node 0.250000...

List: [0.15 | 999]  [0.15 | 1]  [0.20 | 1]  [0.25 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.150000...

Erasing (min) node 0.150000...

Erasing (new) node 0.300000...

List: [0.20 | 1]  [0.25 | 1]  [0.25 | 999]  [0.30 | 1]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.200000...

Erasing (min) node 0.250000...

Erasing (new) node 0.450000...

List: [0.25 | 999]  [0.30 | 1]  [0.45 | 1]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.250000...

Erasing (min) node 0.300000...

Creating (new) node 0.550000...

List: [0.45 | 1]  [0.55 | 1]

1. STEP:

Erasing (min) node 0.450000...

Erasing (min) node 0.550000...

Creating (new) node 1.000000...

List: [1.00 | 1]

*General idea**

In every step two minimal nodes get deleted from list, and one new node gets inserted into the list. The node that gets inserted has the value of *t* for 1 bigger then the greatest in the list, except that it does not compare itself to the *t* value of 999. If the greatest in the list has *t* = 999, then the one inserted will have 1.

*Find greatest t*:

```
int max_t(node *nodes, int num, double p){
int max_t= 0;
int i;
for(i=0; i<num; i+=1){
    if(nodes[i].p== p && nodes[i].t != 999){
        if(nodes[i].t > max_t){
            max_t = nodes[i].t;
        }
    }
}
return max_t;
```

Main code:

```
node *nodes = malloc(num_of_nodes*sizeof(node));
int i;
for(i=0; i<num_of_nodes; i+=1){
    node n;
    n.t = 999;
    n.p = *(probabs+ i);
    *(nodes+i) = n;
}

qsort(nodes, num_of_nodes, sizeof(node), compare_pairs);

while(num_of_nodes> 1){

    printf("\n%d. STEP:\n", z);
    z += 1;

    // 2) Find two min nodes
    node *min_n1 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *min_n2 = malloc(sizeof(node));

    *min_n1 = nodes[0];
    printf("Erasing (min) node %lf...\n", min_n1->p);
    nodes= erase_node(nodes, min_n1, num_of_nodes);
    num_of_nodes -= 1;

    *min_n2 = nodes[0];
    printf("Erasing (min) node %lf...\n", min_n2->p);
    nodes= erase_node(nodes, min_n2, num_of_nodes);
    num_of_nodes-= 1;

    // 3) Create new node, add it to the list
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->p= min_n1->p + min_n2->p;
    double p = new_node->p;
    int max_t = max_t(nodes, num_of_nodes, p);
    new_node->t = max_t + 1;

    printf("Creating (new) node %lf...\n", new_node->p);
    nodes = add_node(nodes, new_node, num_of_nodes);
    num_of_nodes += 1;

    qsort(nodes, num_of_nodes, sizeof(node), compare_pairs);

    printf("List: ");
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<num_of_nodes; k+=1){
        printf("[%.2lf | %d]  ", nodes[k].p, nodes[k].t);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Add / Remove node...

```
node *add_node(node *nodes, node *n, int num){
nodes = realloc(nodes, (num+1)*sizeof(node));
nodes[num] = *n;
return nodes;

node *erase_node(node *nodes, node *n, int num){
int i;
int index = 0;
for(i=0; i<num; i+=1){
    if(nodes_equal(&nodes[i], n)){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

for(i=index; i<num-1; i+=1){
    nodes[i] = nodes[i+1];
}

nodes= realloc(nodes, (num-1)*sizeof(node));

return nodes;
```

}

```
   int nodes_equal(node *n1, node *n2){

    return !memcmp(n1, n2, sizeof(node));
 }
```

Comment: This is a lot of stuff for a question about `qsort()`. Are you sure that `erase_node()` and `add_node()` don't do something that corrupts the list or the heap? Maybe you should have the code  print the list before the qsort in addition to after the qsort.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well, erase_node() only removes node from the list, and add_node() adds it to the end of the list. I can provide the code for those two.

Comment: Didn't understand what you're doing. Just two things come to mind: Are  you sure that the floating point values you think are equal compare as equal, no rounding issue? Are you sure the memcmp in nodes_equal doesn't compare padding you're not interested in but may be different?

Comment: @Whizzil: I'm more interested in having the list printed just before the qsort in addition to after the qsort. Also, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but `nodes_equal()` has an issue where the padding in the `struct node` is being compared - the padding is unspecified (or the moral equivalent), so nodes that have the same `t` and `p` members might not compare as equal according to `memcmp()`.  You should just `return (n1->t == n2->t) && (n1->p == n2->p);` instead of using `memcmp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is with floating point imprecision.  None of the exact decimal numbers 0.1, 0.05 and 0.15 have exact representations in binary floating point.

Using the IEEE 64-bit `double` representation, the closest representable value to 0.15 is slightly less than 0.15, and the closest representable values to 0.05 and 0.10 are slightly greater than 0.05 and 0.10 respectively.  With an implementation using round-to-nearest, this means that if you add up 0.05 and 0.10 you will end up with a number slightly greater than 0.15, and if you set a `double` to 0.15 directly you will end up with a number slightly less than 0.15.  These will *not* compare equal.

This is what is apparently happening in your step 3.  You remove two nodes with the values 0.05 and 0.10 (actually, as discussed their real values are slightly greater than those numbers) and add them together, ending up with a number slightly greater than 0.15.  This compares greater than the existing nodes whose real values are slightly *less* than 0.15, so it sorts after them.

It's not clear if this really *matters* for your algorithm, though?  Doesn't it end up at the same end state anyway? If it does matter, since you are apparently storing probabilities which range from 0.0 to 1.0 inclusive, you could use a decimal fixed point representation instead (eg store the probability multiplied by 10000 in a `long int` rather than a `double`, then just divide by 10000 for display).

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, that was the problem. I did as you suggested (multiplied the probabilities with 100000 and stored them in a long int), and it completely solved my problem.

It does matter since the algorithm does not end up in the same state. It is a Huffman coding algorithm, and although it was generating valid Huffman codes, I needed to follow the common convention of Huffman coding, for which this was important because, numerically, codes were different that way.